# How to dynamically load components in routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm a Vue newbie and I'm experimenting with vue-router and dynamic loading of components without using any additional libraries (so no webpack or similar).

I have created an index page and set up a router. When I first load the page I can see that `subpage.js` has not been loaded, and when I click the `<router-link>` I can see that the `subpage.js` file is loaded. However, the URL does not change, nor does the component appear.

This is what I have so far:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1>Hello App!</h1>
      <router-link to="/subpage">To subpage</router-link>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/subpage', component: () => import('./subpage.js') }
  ]
})

const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app');
```

**subpage.js**

```
export default {
    name: 'SubPage',
    template: '<div>SubPage path: {{msg}}</div>'
    data: function() {
        return {
            msg: this.$route.path
        }
    }
};
```

So the question boils down to: How can I dynamically load a component?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I dynamically load a component?

Try this:

### `App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    <hr/>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {}
};
</script>
```

### `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './App.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const Home = () => import('./components/Home.vue');
const About = () => import('./components/About.vue');

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes:[
    {path:'/', component: Home},
    {path:'/about',component: About}
  ]
})
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

### `Home.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Home'
};
</script>
```

### `About.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'About'
};
</script>
```

This way, the component `Home` will be automatically loaded.

This is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/48qw3x8mvx

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll give it a look. However, you're doing your imports at the top of the file, which means all the files will be loaded when the page is first loaded, instead of being lazy loaded when the user goes to a specific route. How would you add lazy loading to your example?

Comment: Oh, I see now! I've edited my answer. And also the project on CodeSandbox.

Comment: Looking good. Do you know if there's a way to do all the imports in the route definitions? I'm planning on loading routes from an API, and it would be nice to do everything as close together as possible.

Comment: I've just started with VueJS for 3 months, then I'm so sorry that I couldn't help this additional question. Maybe someone out there knows how to do it, then you might consider making another question.

Comment: @GTHvidsten You might consider accepting or voting an answer if it does help :) That would be very nice of you to do that :)

Comment: I will, but I always make it a policy to wait at least a few days to accept to let others get a chance to answer as well ;)

Comment: I finally got around to test this, and I'm sorry to say this didn't work. I changed my main.js to load the subpage before the router definition: `const subpage = () => import('./subpage.js');` and using this variable in the route definition instead of using the import directly: `{ path: '/subpage', component: subpage }`. Subpage.js is loaded dynamically, but the contents of the component and the URL still isn't shown/changed.

Comment: I also noticed your codesandbox-example is using webpack+babel+various other frameworks, whereas I'm looking for a solution without *"any additional libraries (so no webpack or similar)."*

Answer (score 0):

I share your wishes for "as lean as possible" codebase and therefore made this simple example code below (also accessible at https://codesandbox.io/embed/64j8pypr4k).

I am no Vue poweruser either, but when researching I have thought about three possibilities;

- dynamic `import`s,
- `require`js,
- old school JS generated `<script src />` include.

It looks like the last is the easiest and takes least effort too :D Probably not best practice and probably obsolete soon (at least affter dynamic import support).

NB: This example is friendly to more recent browsers (with native Promises, Fetch, Arrow functions...). So - use latest Chrome or Firefox to test :) Supporting older browsers may be done with some polyfills and refactoring etc. But it will add a lot to codebase...

So - dynamically loading components, on demand (and not included before):

---

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Vue lazyload test</title>
  <style>
html,body{
  margin:5px;
  padding:0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav a{
  display:block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

nav, main{
  border:1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top:5px;
}

    .output {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
    <nav>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
      <router-link to="/simple">Simple component</router-link>
      <router-link to="/complex">Not sooo simple component</router-link>
    </nav>
      <main>
          <router-view></router-view>
    </main>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/2.0.1/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function loadComponent(componentName, path) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');

        script.src = path;
        script.async = true;

        script.onload = function() {
          var component = Vue.component(componentName);

          if (component) {
            resolve(component);
          } else {
            reject();
          }
        };
        script.onerror = reject;

        document.body.appendChild(script);
      });
    }

    var router = new VueRouter({
      mode: 'history',
      routes: [
        {
          path: '/',
          component: {
            template: '<div>Home page</div>'
          },
        },
        {
          path: '/simple',
          component: function(resolve, reject) {
            loadComponent('simple', 'simple.js').then(resolve, reject);
          }
        },
         { path: '/complex', component: function(resolve, reject) { loadComponent('complex', 'complex.js').then(resolve, reject); }
        }
      ]
    });

    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router: router,
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

---

**simple.js**:

```
Vue.component("simple", {
  template: "<div>Simple template page loaded from external file</div>"
});
```

---

**complex.js**:

```
Vue.component("complex", {
  template:
    "<div class='complex-content'>Complex template page loaded from external file<br /><br />SubPage path: <i>{{path}}</i><hr /><b>Externally loaded data with some delay:</b><br /> <span class='output' v-html='msg'></span></div>",
  data: function() {
    return {
      path: this.$route.path,
      msg: '<p style="color: yellow;">Please wait...</p>'
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      var that = this;
      setTimeout(() => {
        /* a bit delay to simulate latency :D */
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
            console.log(json);
            that.msg =
              '<p style="color: green;">' + JSON.stringify(json) + "</p>";
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            that.msg =
              '<p style="color: red;">Error fetching: ' + error + "</p>";
          });
      }, 2000);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
});
```

---

As you can see - function `loadComponent()` does the "magic" thing of loading components here.

So it works, but it is probably not the best solution, with regards to the (at least) following:

- inserting  tags with JS can be treated as a security problem
  in the near future,
- performance - synchronously loading files block the thread (this can
  be a major no-no later in app's life),
- I did not test caching etc. Can be a real problem in production,
- You loose the beauty of (Vue) components - like scoped css, html and
  JS that can be automatically bundled with Webpack or something,
- You loose the Babel compilation/transpilation,
- Hot Module Replacement (and state persistance etc) - gone, I believe,
- I probably forgot about other problems that are obvious for
  senior-seniors :D

Hope I helped you though :D

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see how usefull are "new" dynamic imports today (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import), so I did some experiments with it. They do make async imports way easier and below is my example code (no Webpack / Babel / just pure Chrome-friendly JS).

I will keep my old answer ([How to dynamically load components in routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566940/how-to-dynamically-load-components-in-routes/52595711#52595711)) for potential reference - loading scripts that way works in more browsers than dynamic imports do (https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import).

So at the end I noticed that you were actually very, very, very close with your work - it was actually just a syntax error when exporting imported JS module (missing comma).

Example below was also working for me (unfortunately Codesandbox's (es)lint does not allow the syntax, but I have checked it locally and it worked (in Chrome, even Firefox does not like the syntax yet: (SyntaxError: the import keyword may only appear in a module) ));

---

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1>Hello App!</h1>
      <router-link to="/temp">To temp</router-link>
      <router-link to="/module">To module</router-link>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**main.js:**

```
'use strict';

const LazyRouteComponent = {
    template: '<div>Route:{{msg}}</div>',
    data: function() {
        return {
            msg: this.$route.path
        }
    }
}


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
        path: '/temp',
        component: {
            template: '<div>Hello temp: {{msg}}</div>',
            data: function() {
                return {
                    msg: this.$route.path
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { path: '/module', name: 'module', component:  () => import('./module.js')},
    { path: '*', component: LazyRouteComponent }
  ]
})

const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app');
```

---

and the key difference, **module.js**:

```
export default {
    name: 'module',
    template: '<div>Test Module loaded ASYNC this.$route.path:{{msg}}</div>',
    data: function () {
       return {
          msg: this.$route.path
       }
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.$nextTick(function () {
        console.log("entire view has been rendered after module loaded Async");
      })
    }
}
```

---

So - allmost exactly like your code - but with all the commas;

**subpage.js**

```
export default {
    name: 'SubPage',
    template: '<div>SubPage path: {{msg}}</div>',
    data: function() {
        return {
            msg: this.$route.path
        }
    }
};
```

So - your code works (i tested it by copy pasting) - you were actually just missing a comma after `template: '<div>SubPage path: {{msg}}</div>'`.

Nevertheless this only seems to work in:

- Chrome >= v63
- Chrome for Android >= v69
- Safari >= v11.1
- IOS Safari >= v11.2

(https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import)...